# css - media query size

Tags: html, css

I am currently using a wide screen monitor and want to adapt my website to normal monitor so if the user is using a wide or normal monitor the size would adapt, trying to simply decrease the width of 4 divs when the screen is smaller but doesnt seem to work

here is my code:

```
<div class="ManagementReportTiles" style="float: left; width: 400px; height: 200px; text-align:center">                      <div><uc2:FontAwesome ID="FontAwesome1" runat="server" FontAwesomeFont="fa_pencil" FontAwesomeStyle="color:orange;" FontAwesomeSize="fa_3x" />  </div></div>
<div class="ManagementReportTiles" style="float: left; width: 400px; height: 200px; text-align:center; margin-left:10px;">  <div><uc2:FontAwesome ID="FontAwesome2" runat="server" FontAwesomeFont="fa_power_off" FontAwesomeStyle="color:red;" FontAwesomeSize="fa_3x" />   </div></div>
<div class="ManagementReportTiles" style="float: left; width: 400px; height: 200px; text-align:center; margin-left:10px;">  <div><uc2:FontAwesome ID="FontAwesome3" runat="server" FontAwesomeFont="fa_copyright" FontAwesomeStyle="color:white;" FontAwesomeSize="fa_3x" /> </div></div>
<div class="ManagementReportTiles" style="float: left; width: 400px; height: 200px; text-align:center; margin-left:10px;">  <div><uc2:FontAwesome ID="FontAwesome4" runat="server" FontAwesomeFont="fa_gear" FontAwesomeStyle="color:blue;" FontAwesomeSize="fa_3x" />       </div></div>
```

and my media query

```
.ManagementReportTiles {
     background-color: #E8E8E8;
        width:100%;
    }

@media screen and (max-width:790px){

    .ManagementReportTiles{
        width:200px;
    }
}
```

At the moment the width of the divs are at 400, but when the screen gets smaller change the width to 200

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Inline styles in a `style` attribute will override the CSS specified in a CSS file. You must change the html to not include width inline.

Comment: @andeersg you can override inline styles with `!important` (although this is dirty and I wouldn't recommend it unless you have no other choice)

Comment: It's possible yes, but I would so strongly not recommend it that I did not mention it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your width is being overwrite by the `width: 400px` in the tag, or you remove this style or you put `width: 200px !important` in css

Comment: many thanks! is there a way for the width of the divs to be adjusted when the window gets smaller? instead of giving it a set value of 200px (like i have)

Comment: You can use percent, give 25% instead of 200px or 400px

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@media screen and (max-width:790px){

    .ManagementReportTiles{
        width:200px !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put this media query instead of your code

```
@media screen and (max-width:790px){
.ManagementReportTiles{
    width:200px!important;
}
```